# Convert JIS X 208 code to UTF-8 in Python

Tags: python, encoding, standards, data-conversion

Let's say I have this Kanji "亜" which is represented in JIS X 208 code in hex form: 0x3021. I want my Python program to convert that code into its UTF-8 form E4BA9C so that I can pass that string (URL-encoded) into my url like this

http://jisho.org/api/v1/search/words?keyword=%E4%BA%9C

I'm using Python 2.7.12 but I'm open to Python 3 solution as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are accessed under ISO 2022 codec.

```
>>> '亜'.encode('iso2022_jp')
b'\x1b$B0!\x1b(B'
```

If I saw those bytes not framed by the escape sequence, I would have to know which version of JIS X 0208 is being used, but I'm entirely pattern matching on Wikipedia at this point anyway.

```
>>> b = b'\033$B' + bytes.fromhex('3021')
>>> c = b.decode('iso2022_jp')
>>> c
'亜'
>>> urllib.parse.quote(c)
'%E4%BA%9C'
```

(This is Python 3.)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I'm wondering if you can offer Python 2 solution as well.

Comment: Also I don't quite understand how did you get the sequence `b'\033$B`. Is this sequence specific to this example or can you use this in general for other JIS X 208 code as well?

Comment: That's what Python gave when I asked to encode in iso2022_jp, and more are listed at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_2022#ISO.2FIEC_2022_character_sets

Answer (score 0):

This solution may not be standard, but it seems to work.

## CODE

```
import urllib.parse


def jis_to_euc_jp(jis_hex: str):
    """
    You can find the rules from this website: https://pentan.info/doc/jis_list.html

    8080 = A1A1 - 2121
    4B8080 = 8FA1C1 - 442141
    """
    int_jis = int(jis_hex, 16)
    step = int('8080', 16) if int_jis <= int('7426', 16) else int('4B8080', 16)
    return hex(int_jis + step).upper()[2:]  # 0X3021 -> 3021


def eucjp_to_utf_16be(eucjp_hex: str):
    byte_ch = bytes.fromhex(eucjp_hex)
    real_char = byte_ch.decode('euc_jp')  # '亜'
    # code = real_str.encode('utf-8').hex().upper()  # E4BA9C
    return real_char


def main():
    for v in ['亜'.encode('utf-8').hex().upper(),  # when glyph is know. E4BA9C

              # only know jis code, to find the real char
              jis_to_euc_jp('3021'),  # B0A1  # the Standard Encodings is provided euc-jp turn to utf-16be, so we need to know the relation between JIS and euc-jp
              eucjp_to_utf_16be(jis_to_euc_jp('3021'))
              ]:
        print(urllib.parse.quote(v))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

```
E4BA9C
B0A1
%E4%BA%9C
```

## REFERENCE

- Standard Encodings: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings
- JIS TABLE: https://pentan.info/doc/jis_list.html