# How to encode/decode JIS X 208, JIS X 212, and JIS X 213 kuten character codes in Python?

Tags: python, character-encoding, cjk

I'm trying to work with [Kanjidic](http://www.edrdg.org/wiki/index.php/KANJIDIC_Project). Specially, the Kanjidic2.xml.gz file. However, Kanjidic encodes several characters in JIS X 0208, JIS X 0212, JIS X 0213.

Example of part of a Kanjidic2.xml entry:

```
<character>
<literal>学</literal> <!-- this is the character I want -->
<codepoint>
<cp_value cp_type="ucs">5b66</cp_value> <!-- unicode hex value -->
<cp_value cp_type="jis208">1-19-56</cp_value> <!-- kuten code -->
</codepoint>
...
<variant var_type="jis208">1-53-60</variant> <!-- more kuten codes -->
<variant var_type="jis208">1-53-61</variant>
<variant var_type="jis212">1-33-55</variant>
```

I can't find JIS X 0208, JIS X 0212, or JIS X 0213 in the available [Python character encodings](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings). All three JIS encodings are included in [ISO 2022](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_2022). [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43239935/convert-jis-x-208-code-to-utf-8-in-python) talks about decoding JIS 208 with ISO 2022, but it doesn't use kuten codes. My attempts to decode a kuten code with ISO 2022 haven't worked so far.

How do I decode these JIS character encodings to get a Japanese kanji character in Python? Ultimately, I want to switch them to UTF-8. Thanks.

Comment: You can't use the ucs hex value (`chr(0x5b66)`)?

Comment: I can. That isn't the issue. The issue is I need to decode the JIS codes. The JIS codes may or may not evaluate to the same character as the ucs hex value. See the Kanjidic website for more information on the <variant> xml tag.

Answer (score 3):

```
kutens = [
          '1-14-02',
          '1-16-01', # 丂 \u4e02                 cp_type="jis212">1-16-01
          '2-01-02', # ↑                         cp_type="jis213">2-01-02
          '1-19-34', # 1-19-34 蛎 b'\xb3\xc2' b'\\u86ce' b'\xe8\x9b\x8e'
          '1-19-56', # 1-19-56 学 b'\xb3\xd8' b'\\u5b66' b'\xe5\xad\xa6'
          '1-19-57', # 1-19-57 岳 b'\xb3\xd9' b'\\u5cb3' b'\xe5\xb2\xb3'
          '1-19-58', # 1-19-58 楽 b'\xb3\xda' b'\\u697d' b'\xe6\xa5\xbd' <cp_value cp_type="jis208">1-19-58</cp_value>
          '1-60-59', # 1-60-59 樂 b'\xdc\xdb' b'\\u6a02' b'\xe6\xa8\x82' <variant var_type="jis208">1-60-59</variant>
          '1-53-60', # 
          '1-53-61', # 
          '1-33-55', #
          '2-05-05'  #  \U000213C4
         ]
for kuten in kutens:
    # ToDo/Unclear:
    #      0x00..0x7F: ASCII
    #      0x8E{A1..FE}: JISX0201 Katakana, with prefix 0x8E, offset by +0x80.
    plan, ku, ten = kuten.split('-')
    #  get (Raw) JIS  ↓↓↓↓↓↓
    euc0 = ( int( ku) + 0x20 ) | 0x80
    euc1 = ( int(ten) + 0x20 ) | 0x80
    #  turn on bit-8 (MSB)     ↑↑↑↑↑↑
    if plan == '1':
        #  0x{A1..FE}{A1..FE}: JISX0213 plane 1, offset by +0x8080.
        euc = bytearray([euc0,euc1]).decode('euc_jisx0213','replace')
    else:
        # 0x8F{A1..FE}{A1..FE}: JISX0213 plane 2, with prefix 0x8F, offset by +0x8080.
        euc = bytearray([0x8f,euc0,euc1]).decode('euc_jisx0213','replace')
    print( kuten, euc,
                  repr(euc.encode('euc_jisx0213'  , 'backslashreplace')).ljust(15),
                  repr(euc.encode('unicode-escape', 'backslashreplace')).ljust(15),
                  euc.encode('utf-8', 'backslashreplace'))
```

Please note my zero skill in Japanese. Above code snippet is based on the following resources:

- [EUC-JP encoding](https://www.sljfaq.org/afaq/encodings.html#encodings-EUC-JP): how *JIS X 0201*, *JIS X 0208* and *JIS X 0212* character set is encoded (table) and *JIS X 0213* note,
- [The structure of EUC-JISX0213](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/iconvdata/euc-jisx0213.c.html):

> `0x00..0x7F`: ASCII
>
> `0x8E{A1..FE}`: JISX0201 Katakana, with prefix 0x8E, offset by +0x80.
>
> `0x8F{A1..FE}{A1..FE}`: JISX0213 plane 2, with prefix 0x8F, offset by +0x8080.
>
> `0x{A1..FE}{A1..FE}`: JISX0213 plane 1, offset by +0x8080.

- [*Jim Breen*'s *CODING.INF*](http://nihongo.monash.edu/coding_inf.html) - how to compute *EUC coding* from *kuten code* (or *nhotta*'s [Kuten code to Unicode](http://unicode-iphone.blogspot.com/2010/05/kuten-code-to-unicode.html))

**Output** for given sample data: `.\SO\64486353a.py`

```
1-14-02  b'\xae\xa2'     b'\\U0002000b'  b'\xf0\xa0\x80\x8b'
1-16-01 亜 b'\xb0\xa1'     b'\\u4e9c'      b'\xe4\xba\x9c'
2-01-02 丂 b'\x8f\xa1\xa2' b'\\u4e02'      b'\xe4\xb8\x82'
1-19-34 蛎 b'\xb3\xc2'     b'\\u86ce'      b'\xe8\x9b\x8e'
1-19-56 学 b'\xb3\xd8'     b'\\u5b66'      b'\xe5\xad\xa6'
1-19-57 岳 b'\xb3\xd9'     b'\\u5cb3'      b'\xe5\xb2\xb3'
1-19-58 楽 b'\xb3\xda'     b'\\u697d'      b'\xe6\xa5\xbd'
1-60-59 樂 b'\xdc\xdb'     b'\\u6a02'      b'\xe6\xa8\x82'
1-53-60 學 b'\xd5\xdc'     b'\\u5b78'      b'\xe5\xad\xb8'
1-53-61 斈 b'\xd5\xdd'     b'\\u6588'      b'\xe6\x96\x88'
1-33-55 宋 b'\xc1\xd7'     b'\\u5b8b'      b'\xe5\xae\x8b'
2-05-05  b'\x8f\xa5\xa5' b'\\U000213c4'  b'\xf0\xa1\x8f\x84'
```